# PL/SQL: Best practice for fetching 2 or more joined tables from a cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, record

I've heard that it's a good practice to define your records in PL/SQL by using the %ROWTYPE attribute. This saves typing and allows your package to continue functioning even when a column is added or deleted. (Correct me if I'm wrong!)

However, when I am fetching from a cursor that involves a join, I find that I have to fetch into a programmer-defined record that includes a (quite-possibly long) hand-written list of every column returned by the join.

So my question is:
Is it possible to fetch into nested records, or fetch into a list of records, or do *something* to avoid such an ugly kludge? Everything I've tried leads to an error about the record not matching what's being returned by the cursor.

Returning the result of a join using a cursor seems like such a common use-case to me that it's strange that nothing related to this comes up in a search.

Thank you.

Comment: I assume when you say "even when a row is added or deleted." you meant "even when a column is added or deleted."

Comment: This is quite far from a kludge. It's exactly the way it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 8):

You can user cursor%rowtype.

Sample:

```
declare
cursor c_c is
select emp.*, dept.* -- use aliasses if columns have same name
from emp
,    dept; -- for sample no join condition

r_c c_c%rowtype; 

begin
  for r_c in c_c loop -- with for loop even the definition of r_c is not needed.
  ...
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Wow! You rock. I never would have thought of that.

Thanks.

Comment: In the usage example you give (for r_c in c_c ...), it's not even necessary to declare the r_c variable or its type.  The for loop does that implicitly.  But if you need to do explicit FETCHes this is definitely useful.

Answer (score 5):

Why even bother with the cursor declaration?

This is equivalent.

```
begin
  for r_c in (select emp.*, dept.* from emp, dept) loop
  ...
  end loop;
end;
```

I see in your comment you mention this. But I see the explicit cursor syntax used so much, i think it's important to show.